# openssl ssl_accept question with client certs

Tags: ssl, openssl

I've got a working c++ system where I make an ssl connection between a client and a server using the C openssl library on both sides.

The system uses client authentication by requiring a client cert as part of the connection. The client cert is self signed, it is validated on the server by the ca.pem from the system that is signing the self signed certs.

The server cert was issued by digikey.

My understanding is that there is no relationship between the client's validation of the server certificate (which it validates on the client side) and the server's validation of the client [self signed] certificate which is validated on the server with my provided ca.pem.

However I'm running into a problem when I change the server cert to one that is signed by letsencrypt.

I get this error accepting connections:

error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:s3_pkt.c:1487:SSL alert number 48

Unknown CA. Ahhh, but which?

I tried removing the client certificate requirement as a test and I was able to make the connection, so clearly the client is happy to validate the new letsencrypt server cert.

So it would seem that the server was unable to validate the client certificate. But that makes no sense, since none of that has changed, the client certificate is the same, and the server's ca.pem to validate that cert is the same.

Why would changing the server cert affect how the client cert is validated?

Is there something about the request the server is making to the client asking for a client cert including "letencrypt" for the subject or something like that? I'm a bit hazy on how the client cert request works.

Is there a way to get more information out of the ssl error, more verbose logging from the library?

I've run openssl verify commands on the command line to validate by hand that the client's ca.pem list of trusted roots can verify the letsencrypt cert and that the server's ca.pem can verify the client cert (as it always has)

So.... what am I doing wrong?

Any ideas? suggestions? Things to try?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

So I had to rebuild openssl but I got tracing on and on the server side, I get this:

```
Received Record
Header:
  Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
  Content Type = Alert (21)
  Length = 2
    Level=fatal(2), description=unknown CA(48)
```

which leads me to believe now that the problem is on the client side.
The previous message was sent from the server:

```
Sent Record
Header:
  Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
  Content Type = Handshake (22)
  Length = 46
    CertificateRequest, Length=38
      certificate_types (len=3)
        rsa_sign (1)
        dss_sign (2)
        ecdsa_sign (64)
      signature_algorithms (len=30)
        sha512+rsa (6+1)
        sha512+dsa (6+2)
        sha512+ecdsa (6+3)
        sha384+rsa (5+1)
        sha384+dsa (5+2)
        sha384+ecdsa (5+3)
        sha256+rsa (4+1)
        sha256+dsa (4+2)
        sha256+ecdsa (4+3)
        sha224+rsa (3+1)
        sha224+dsa (3+2)
        sha224+ecdsa (3+3)
        sha1+rsa (2+1)
        sha1+dsa (2+2)
        sha1+ecdsa (2+3)
      certificate_authorities (len=0)
```

So that means that the server is offering no suggestions as to what to match client certs for, and the client doesn't like that? Not sure this helps except pointing me to the fact that the problem is likely on the client.

Answer (score 0):

So for all followers, I figured it out.

the tipoff was from the tracing

```
Received Record
Header:
  Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
  Content Type = Alert (21)
  Length = 2
    Level=fatal(2), description=unknown CA(48)
```

showing that the server was in fact complaining about a client side problem (and the client did not, sigh)

so once I realized it was complaining about the server cert on the client (on the server), I realized I just didn't have all of the root certs and intermediates available on the client for the new server cert to be verified. I added them, and voila, ssl connection.
ssl errors can be a bit misleading.

doesn't explain why my client-less connection worked... maybe I messed up that test somehow.